# JavaScript library pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the basic pattern for creating a JavaScript library (class). I want to do it in such a way that it doesn't pollute the global namespace with a bunch of junk, but allowing for the class to have instance variables and public methods that modify those instance variables.

Consider the following toy example. I want to make a class `Foo`. It should contain an instance member, `bar`, which is a number. There should be a constructor for `Foo` that takes a number and initializes its instance `bar` with that number. There should be an instance method that I can call on a `Foo` object to modify `bar`. Maybe the code that uses the library looks like this:

```
var foo1 = new Foo(1);
var foo2 = new Foo(2);
console.log(foo1.bar); // should print "1"
console.log(foo2.bar); // should print "2"
foo2.changeBar(42);
console.log(foo1.bar); // should print "1"
console.log(foo2.bar); // should print "42"
```

The resultant `foo.js` would be used by a Web app and therefore included via a script tag in the HTML.

I've done a bit of searching with Google but I have yet to find a single, concise, generic outline of how to design a JavaScript class (used as a library).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(function () {
    Foo = function (num) {
         this.changeBar(num);
    };

    var privateMethod = function (x) {
        if (this.bar === 999) {
            this.bar = x;
        }
    };

    Foo.prototype.changeBar = function (num) {
        this.bar = num;
        privateMethod.call(this, 1);
    };

}());
```

That is the simplest way of doing it. You don't need to include the definition in a closure, more of a style thing.

Comment: +1 as well.  The closure has some subtle advantages.  You can define "private" functions inside the closure that your prototype and member functions can call.

Comment: @selbie how would such a private function be defined, and how would it be called?

Comment: I've edited Evan's answer above to include a private method.  "privateMethod" function can not be called except by other functions within the closure.

Comment: @selbie and Evan, actually, now that I've tried it, the privateMethod doesn't work. "this" gets bound to DOMWindow (I believe because it's forming a closure?)

Comment: Probably because your DOM event isn't binded to function correctly.  Do something click this:  "e.onclick = function() { foo.changeBar();};}"  Or use the "bind" keyword to explicitly set the this point apriorit before a callback.

Comment: JSLint says: `Problem at line 2 character 5: 'Foo' was used before it was defined.` How can that warning be fixed?

Answer (score 11):

Building up on Evan's answer, to showcase some more possibilites. Most normal cases only use some of these though.

```
(function() {
    //When we create variables inside a function they can only be seen by other
    // inner functions. Wraping all our code here makes sure noone gets to see
    // the private stuff.

    //The first opening parenthesis is required for Javascript to parse it
    //correctly though


    //this is the constructor function
    //Note how we set a global variable (Foo) to make it available outside.
    Foo = function(num, another_num) {

        this.changeBar(num);

        //sometimes you will want to make a method that modifies a variable
        //that can't be acessed via this.xxx. You can use a closure here for that
        //(there are some performance considerations though)

        this.baz = function(){
            console.log(another_num);
        }

        //Setting methods "by hand" like this is also useful if you want to
        //do multiple inheritance, since you can just set all methods of the
        //second class by hand here if you want.
    }

    //Things on Foo.prototype will be available for all Foo objects,
    // via prototypal inheritance magic.
    Foo.prototype.changeBar = function(num) {
        this.bar = num;
    }

    var a_secret_variable = 42;

    function my_private_function(){
        console.log(a_secret_variable);
    }

    //All private variables can be normaly used (by functions that can see them).
    Foo.prototype.use_magic = function(){
        my_private_function();
    }

}());
 //The "fake" function is imediatelly called,
 //so in the end all it does is create a inner scope.
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) is probably the most popular pattern used today.

```
var Foo = (function() {
    var _thisIsAPrivateVar;

    function thisIsAPrivateMethod() {
    }

    return {
        thisIsAPublicMethod : function() {
            // can still access the "private" variable and method
        }
    };

})();
```