# Problems in accessing global variables

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some problems in accessing a global variable attached to the window in javascript.
Here is my code snippet which I have embedded in my index page using script tag lets say

```
var Geolocation = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.errors = {
    TIMEOUT: 1,
    POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2,
    PERMISSION_DENIED: 3,
    UNKNOWN_ERROR: 4
  };

  self.getCurrentPosition = function( success, error, options ) {
    // simulate the wait for the user choice
    var geoIntervalId = window.setInterval(function( ) {
      if ( state != null ) {
        window.clearInterval(geoIntervalId);

        switch( state ) {
          case 'ok':
            success(new Position(latitude, longitude));
            break;
          case 'timeout': case 'position_unavailable': case 'permission_denied':
            error( new GeolocationError( self.errors[state.toUpperCase()] ) );
            break;
          default:
            error( new GeolocationError( self.errors.UNKNOWN_ERROR ) );
        }
      }
    }, 100); // ms
  };
}

var Position = function( lat, lng ) {
  this.coords = new Coordinates(lat, lng);
}

var Coordinates = function( lat, lng ) {
  this.latitude  = lat;
  this.longitude = lng;
}

var GeolocationError = function( code ) {
  this.TIMEOUT = 1;
  this.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
  this.PERMISSION_DENIED = 3;
  this.UNKNOWN_ERROR = 4;

  this.code = code;
}

var state     = null,
    latitude  = null,
    longitude = null;

window.geolocation_provider = new Geolocation();
```

After this I have included another javascript file say test.js in the index file again using  the script tag. Now when I try to access the window.geolocation_provider variable, it is turning out to be null. Why is it so

Comment: My first recommendation would be check order of execution when dealing with external .js files. That was a common problem I occoured when dealing with JS. It would cause null to appear frequently.

Comment: Is the value null or undefined? An issue of order of execution would surely result in an undefined value. To verify if the issue is related to the second file, place "alert (window.geolocation_provider) after the call to Geolocation and see what the value is. Also in the test.js file how are you referring to  geiolocation_provider?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that certain files execute before / after other files; ideally, this problem is solved by ensuring that all your javascript function definitions are loaded before executing any important code.

You may want to take a look at the [Module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) in javascript. There are a few other questions that deal with this problem, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823669/javascript-library-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function(window){
  var Geolocation = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.errors = {
    TIMEOUT: 1,
    POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2,
    PERMISSION_DENIED: 3,
    UNKNOWN_ERROR: 4
  };

  self.getCurrentPosition = function( success, error, options ) {
    // simulate the wait for the user choice
    var geoIntervalId = window.setInterval(function( ) {
      if ( state !== null ) {
        window.clearInterval(geoIntervalId);

        switch( state ) {
          case 'ok':
            success(new Position(latitude, longitude));
            break;
          case 'timeout': case 'position_unavailable': case 'permission_denied':
            error( new GeolocationError( self.errors[state.toUpperCase()] ) );
            break;
          default:
            error( new GeolocationError( self.errors.UNKNOWN_ERROR ) );
        }
      }
    }, 100); // ms
  };
};

var Position = function( lat, lng ) {
  this.coords = new Coordinates(lat, lng);
};

var Coordinates = function( lat, lng ) {
  this.latitude  = lat;
  this.longitude = lng;
};

var GeolocationError = function( code ) {
  this.TIMEOUT = 1;
  this.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
  this.PERMISSION_DENIED = 3;
  this.UNKNOWN_ERROR = 4;

  this.code = code;
};

var state     = null,
    latitude  = null,
    longitude = null;
if(window.geolocation_provider === undefined){
    window.geolocation_provider = new Geolocation();
}
})(window ? window : this)
```